# How did 15th century Dutch “Van Lanckvelt” correspond to neo-Latin “Macropedius”?

Tags: etymology, ancient-greek, new-latin

The 15th-century Dutch humanist *[Georgius Macropedius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macropedius)* was originally named *Joris van Lanckvelt*, and his adopted Latin name is generally described as a direct Latinisation of that, without further explanation — but I don’t quite follow how.  *Joris* corresponding to *Georgius* is standard, and *Lanck-* (long, tall) becoming *Macro-* (long, large) seems clear.  But **how does *-velt* correspond to *-pedius*?**  The only reading for *velt* I can see is as equivalent to modern Dutch [*veld*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/veld#Dutch) (field); meanwhile the only (neo-)Latin readings I can see for *pedius* would be based on either *pes* (foot), as in *quadruped*, or *paidea* (education, childhood), as in *encyclopaedia*.

In case it helps to pin down possible alternative readings on the Dutch side, I’ve also seen mentions of a Germanised form *von Langefeld* (which fits with the reading of *velt*/*feld* as *field*).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the Greek word [πεδίον](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpedi%2Fon2) (*pedion*), which means a "plain" or "field." In ancient Greek, it's clearly distinct from [παίδιον](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpai%2Fdion) (*paidion*), "a little child," from παῖς, παιδός (*pais, paidos*).

In Medieval Latin, the diphthong /ai/ was reduced to /e/, and by analogy Greek words borrowed into Latin had their /αι/ diphthong reduced to /e/ as well. So the two different roots became homophones in later times. I don't believe we have many (or any?) words derived from πεδίον (*pedion*), so you won't typically find it in collections of Greek roots.

From παιδός/παίδιον, we also get the Greek word [παιδεία](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpaidei%2Fa) (*paideia*), from which the suffix *-pedia* (e.g. in "encyclopedia") derives. And that's why you see *encyclopaedia* as an alternate spelling, but *Macropaedius* would be an etymological mistake.

This should also not be confused for the Latin root *pes, pedis*, which does, as you note, mean foot. But usually for names like these, the tendency is to stick to a single language. Since *macro-* is Greek (*magn-* would be the Latinized root, like in *magnify*), so too then should we expect the second element to be Greek. Thus von Königsberg turned into Regiomontanus, with both roots being Latin; for an exception, you have the physician Paracelsus (*para*- is Greek meaning "next to," *celsus* is Latin meaning "lofty"), but the *celsus* element was likely a nod to the Roman medical writer Celsus.

Comment: Indeed, rare in plain English, but see [pedion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pedion), [pedosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedosphere), [pedotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedotope).